# Caffe feature extraction blocks other executing threads (Qt / C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, blocking, caffe

**Background**

I am developing a Qt application with three threads: `main`, `thread1`, and `thread2`.

- `main` creates, starts, and displays the results of `thread1` and
  `thread2`, while also iteratively feeding them input.
- `thread1` performs an intensive computation (~1s) once every *n*
  inputs, ignoring all other inputs. The majority of this time is spent on feature extraction
  using the [Caffe framework](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/).
- `thread2` performs fast computations (~20ms) on every input. But
  every *n+1* inputs depend on the output of feeding input *n* to `thread1`.

During thread execution, `thread1` appears to block `thread2` when extracting features using the Caffe network. However, `thread1` does **not** block `thread2` during other processing steps (e.g. network input preprocessing).

At first, I thought this was caused by an unmet dependency: i.e. `thread1` "blocks" `thread2` because input (for example) *2n + 1* is ready to be processed by `thread2` but input *2n* has not been fully processed by `thread1`.

However, from analysing the execution flow, I noticed this "blocking" behaviour was occurring whilst dependencies were met: i.e. let *n* = 10, `thread2` would pause execution at input 15 while `thread1` was extracting Caffe features from input 20.

**Question**

How do I prevent `thread2` from blocking `thread1` during Caffe feature extraction?

**Code**

Below is a stripped-down version of my code, which shows the key components and logic of my program.

I have highlighted the problem in comments `// !!! PROBLEM: ...`, which can be found in `thread1worker.cpp` and `featureengine.cpp`.

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qRegisterMetaType<Mat>("Mat");

    Camera camera; // grabs camera frame every 30ms, emitting newFrame(frame)


    /* thread1 */

    QThread* thread1 = new QThread();
    Thread1Worker* thread1_worker = new Thread1Worker();
    thread1_worker->moveToThread(thread1);

    QThread::connect(&camera, SIGNAL(newFrame(Mat)),
                     thread1_worker, SLOT(doWork(Mat)));
    QThread::connect(thread1, SIGNAL(finished()),
                     thread1_worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QThread::connect(thread1, SIGNAL(finished()),
                     thread1, SLOT(deleteLater()));


    /* thread2 */

    ImageQueue* thread2_images = new ImageQueue();
    QThread::connect(camera, SIGNAL(newFrame(Mat)),
                     thread2_images, SLOT(add(Mat)));

    QThread* thread2 = new QThread();
    Thread2Worker* thread2_worker = new Thread2Worker(thread2_images);
    thread2_worker->moveToThread(thread2);

    QThread::connect(thread2_worker, SIGNAL(workFinished(OutputType)),
                     thread2_worker, SLOT(addThread1Result(OutputType)));
    QThread::connect(thread2, SIGNAL(finished()),
                     thread2_worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QThread::connect(thread2, SIGNAL(finished()),
                     thread2, SLOT(deleteLater()));


    /* start threads */

    thread1->start();
    thread2->start();
    camera->start();

    return app.exec();
}
```

thread1worker.cpp:

```
Thread1Worker::Thread1Worker()
{
    thread1_interval = 10; // this is "n"
    is_initialized = false;
}

void Thread1Worker::doWork(Mat frame)
{
    if (!is_initialized)
        initialize();

    // process only every nth frame
    if (!isThread1Frame())
        return;

    // ... break frame up into multiple image patches

    // !!! PROBLEM: this call blocks thread2
    vector<vector<float> > features = feature_engine->extractFeatures(patches);

    // ... use features to compute output

    frame_count++;

    emit workFinished(output);
}

void Thread1Worker::initialize()
{
    InitGoogleLogging("caffe-demo");
    feature_engine = new FeatureEngine();
    is_initialized = true;
}

bool Thread1Worker::isThread1Frame()
{
    return frame_count % thread1_interval == 0;
}
```

thread2worker.cpp:

```
void Thread2Worker::addThread1Result(OutputType output)
{
    if (!is_initialized)
        initialize();

    thread1_output_queue.push(output);
    thread1_count++;

    processFrames();
}

void Thread2Worker::processFrames()
{
    size_t num_process = (thread1_count * thread1_interval) - process_count;
    size_t num_queue = thread2_images->size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_process && i < num_queue; i++)
    {
        Mat frame = thread2_images->get();

        if (isThread1Frame()
        {
            curr_result = thread1_output_queue.front();
            thread1_output_queue.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            curr_result = propagator->propagate(prev_result);
        }

        // update
        prev_result = curr_result;

        emit resultReady(curr_result);
    }
}

void Thread2Worker::initialize()
{
    propagator = new Propagator();
    is_initialized = true;
}

bool Thread2Worker::isThread1Frame()
{
    return process_count % thread1_interval == 0;
}
```

featureengine.cpp:

```
vector<vector<float> > FeatureEngine::extractFeatures(const vector<Mat>& images)
{
    // setup Caffe network for feature extraction:

    Blob<float>* input_layer = net->input_blobs()[0];

    int num_images = images.size();
    int height = input_geometry.height;
    int width = input_geometry.width;
    input_layer->Reshape(num_images, num_channels, height, width);
    net->Reshape();

    vector<Mat> input_channels;
    wrapInputLayer(input_channels);
    preprocess(images, &input_channels);


    // !!! PROBLEM: this ~1s computation blocks thread2
    // details: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/net.cpp#L594
    net->ForwardPrefilled();

    // copy Caffe network output to features vector
    vector<vector<float> > features;
    // ...

    return features;
}
```

Comment: Without a code example, its difficult to give a concise answer.  Look into std::mutex, as well as std::future/std::promise for safe thread synchronization.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I have added code that illustrates the problem I am having. I  am using `QMutex` to protect access to shared data (i.e. wrapping lock/unlock around shared variable access), but the blocking problem occurs during a function that does not use any shared data. I will have a closer look. Any other ideas from seeing the code?